# Apparently simple simplification fails?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Consider the expression

```
expr = E^x Sqrt[1 - E^(-4 x)] - Sqrt[-E^(-2 x) + E^(2 x)]
```

At least for `x>0` I would expect this to be equal to zero (because `E^x` is manifestly positive, so that it should only influence the scale when both square roots are expressed in polar coordinates as a complex number). But if I try

```
Assuming[x > 0, expr // FullSimplify]
```

> `E^x Sqrt[1 - E^(-4 x)] - E^-x Sqrt[-1 + E^(4 x)]`

The result is a bit disappointing. It should still be zero (one can even verify it by plotting some range of `x>0`), but Mathematica does not seem to see it. How should I modify the command such that Mathematica properly returns zero after simplification?

Comment: `FullSimplify[expr^2, x > 0]` works though.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yes, I noticed that changing the function a little leads to better simplification. But `expr` itself should be zero too. Basically, I am trying to understand what Mathematica gets hung up on here. To have a larger toolbox for more complicated/less obvious examples.

Comment: `FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[expr], x>0]`

Comment: @W.Mason  With what version of Mathematica did `FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[expr], x>0]` simplify to zero?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Maybe a 11.2 then, it seems that this method fails in 11.3 somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute E^x

```
expr[x_] = E^x Sqrt[1 - E^(-4 x)] - Sqrt[-E^(-2 x) + E^(2 x)];

sol = Solve[E^x == y, x, Reals]

(*   {{x -> ConditionalExpression[Log[y], y > 0]}}   *)

FullSimplify[expr[x /. First@sol], y > 0]

(*   0   *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another way:

```
$Version
(* "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)

expr = E^x*Sqrt[1 - E^(-4 x)] - Sqrt[-E^(-2 x) + E^(2 x)];

FullSimplify[FullSimplify[expr // ComplexExpand, x > 0] // ComplexExpand, x > 0]
(* 0 *)
```